# Reading records from a FoxBASE database file

Tags: c#, performance, file

I'm working on implementing a library that can read/write from FoxBASE files in C#. I can't use ODBC for this, because it's not supported in .NET core.

I've got the reading working, but it's incredibly slow. I've tried doing some profiling on it, but the performance report doesn't list specific line numbers or function names, so it's hard to tell where the bottlenecks are.

This is the table class I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using DataConverter.Database.Transformers;

namespace DataConverter.Database.Toolbox.FoxPro
{
    public class FoxProTable<T> : IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T: new()
    {

        [Flags]
        private enum TableAttribute
        {
            HasCDX,
            HasMemoField,
            IsDatabase
        }

        private string FileLocation { get; }
        private DbfFileType _fileType;
        private int _recordCount;
        private int _firstRecordPosition;
        private int _dataRecordLength;
        private TableAttribute _tableAttributes;
        private int _codePageMark;
        private string _tableName;
        protected readonly List<FoxProField> Fields = new List<FoxProField>();
        private int _filePosition;
        private readonly Dictionary<MemberInfo, string> _fieldNameCache = new Dictionary<MemberInfo, string>();
        private readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _propertyCache = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Transformer> _transformerCache = new Dictionary<Type, Transformer>();
        private FileStream _file;
        # Keep the file open so that we don't have to open/close it on every record.
        # Ideally this also means fewer seeks.
        private FileStream File => _file ?? (_file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileLocation));

        private readonly List<T> _records = new List<T>();
        private int _recordPosition = -1;

        public FoxProTable()
        {
        }

        public FoxProTable(string filePath, string tableName)
        {
            _tableName = tableName;
            FileLocation = Path.Combine(filePath, tableName);
            ReadHeader();
        }

        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }

        private string GetFieldName(MemberInfo property)
        {
            if (_fieldNameCache.TryGetValue(property, out var fieldName)) return fieldName;
            fieldName = ((FieldAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(FieldAttribute)))?.Name;
            _fieldNameCache[property] = fieldName;
            return fieldName;
        }

        # Translate a data field from an array of bytes into its human readable version.
        private static object TranslateBuffer(IReadOnlyCollection<byte> buffer, FoxProField field)
        {
            switch (field.DataType)
            {
                case DbfDataType.Integer:
                case DbfDataType.Numeric:
                    return int.TryParse(string.Join("", buffer.Select(x => (char)x)).TrimEnd(), out var val) ? val : 0;
                case DbfDataType.Character:
                    return string.Join("", buffer.Select(x => (char) x));
                case DbfDataType.Currency:
                    return int.Parse(string.Join("", buffer.Select(x => (char)x)).TrimEnd()) / Math.Pow(10, 4);
                case DbfDataType.Double:
                    return int.Parse(string.Join("", buffer.Select(x => (char)x)).TrimEnd());
                case DbfDataType.Float:
                    return int.Parse(string.Join("", buffer.Select(x => (char)x)).TrimEnd()) / Math.Pow(10, field.NumberOfDecimalPlaces);
                case DbfDataType.Date:
                    var validYear = int.TryParse(string.Join("", buffer.Take(4).Select(x => (char)x)), out var year);
                    var validMonth = int.TryParse(string.Join("", buffer.Skip(4).Take(2).Select(x => (char)x)), out var month);
                    var validDay = int.TryParse(string.Join("", buffer.Skip(6).Take(2).Select(x => (char)x)), out var day);
                    if (validDay && validMonth && validYear) return new DateTime(year, month, day);
                    return null;
                case DbfDataType.Logical:
                    return (char)buffer.Single() == 'T';
                case DbfDataType.DateTime:
                case DbfDataType.General:
                case DbfDataType.Memo:
                case DbfDataType.Picture:
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"{field.DataType} fields are not supported yet.");
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(field), field.DataType, null);
            }
        }

        private T ReadRecord()
        {
            # Make sure we're reading the correct position.
            if (File.Position != _filePosition) File.Seek(_filePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var record = new T();

            # Read in the array of bytes that represent the next record.
            var dataBuffer = new byte[_dataRecordLength];
            File.Read(dataBuffer, 0, _dataRecordLength);
            _filePosition += _dataRecordLength;

            if (dataBuffer.Length < _dataRecordLength)
                throw new EndOfStreamException();

            # For each field in the FoxBASE table, we try to match it to a field on the model.
            foreach (var field in Fields)
            {
                # If we already found the property once, there's no need to incur the cost of reflecting the model to get the PropertyInfo.
                if (!_propertyCache.TryGetValue(field.FieldName, out var property))
                {
                    # FieldAttribute allows you to define a name for the field that's not the same as the field name in the table.
                    property = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(field.FieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                                        || (GetFieldName(x)?.Equals(field.FieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false));
                }
                if (property == null) continue;
                # For reasons unknown to me, the displacement in the header is always high by 2.
                var fieldStart = field.Displacement - 2;
                var fieldLength = field.LengthInBytes;

                # Get the value from the byte slice that represents the field in the database file/
                dynamic value = TranslateBuffer(dataBuffer.Skip(fieldStart).Take(fieldLength).ToArray(), field);
                var transformerType = ((FieldAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(FieldAttribute)))?
                    .Transformer;
                # If there's a transformer associated with the field, load it.
                if (transformerType != null)
                {
                    if (!_transformerCache.TryGetValue(transformerType, out var transformer))
                    {
                        transformer = (Transformer)Activator.CreateInstance(transformerType);
                        _transformerCache.Add(transformerType, transformer);
                    }
                    value = transformer.Transform(value);
                }
                property.SetValue(record, value);
            }
            return record;
        }

        # This method can be ignored. It just reads the metadata from the header.
        private void ReadHeader()
        {
            var tableInfoBuffer = new byte[32];
            File.Read(tableInfoBuffer, 0, 32);

            var fileType = tableInfoBuffer[0];
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DbfFileType), (int)fileType))
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{FileLocation} is not a supported file type. It starts with {fileType}");
            _fileType = (DbfFileType) fileType;

            var lastUpdateYear = (int)tableInfoBuffer[1];
            var lastUpdateMonth = tableInfoBuffer[2];
            var lastUpdateDay = tableInfoBuffer[3];
            lastUpdateYear += lastUpdateYear + 2000 > DateTime.Today.Year ? 1900 : 2000;
            LastUpdate = new DateTime(lastUpdateYear, lastUpdateMonth, lastUpdateDay);

            _recordCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(tableInfoBuffer, 4);

            _firstRecordPosition = BitConverter.ToInt16(tableInfoBuffer, 8);

            _dataRecordLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(tableInfoBuffer, 10);

            _tableAttributes = (TableAttribute)tableInfoBuffer[27];
            _codePageMark = tableInfoBuffer[28];
            var fieldInfoBuffer = new byte[32];
            while (true)
            {
                File.Read(fieldInfoBuffer, 0, 32);
                if (fieldInfoBuffer[0] == 0x0D) break;
                Fields.Add(new FoxProField(fieldInfoBuffer));
            }
            _filePosition = _firstRecordPosition;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            try
            {
                _recordPosition++;
                if (_recordPosition > _recordCount) return false;
                var nextRecord = ReadRecord();
                _records.Add(nextRecord);
                return true;

            }
            catch (EndOfStreamException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _recordPosition = -1;
        }

        public T Current => _records[_recordPosition];

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

These are the two helper classes:

Transformer:

```
using System;
namespace DataConverter.Database.Transformers.RoadRunner
{
    public class FoxProTransformer : Transformer
    {
        public override object Transform(object value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case string sValue:
                    return sValue.Equals("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                default:
                    return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FieldAttribute:

```
using System;

namespace DataConverter.Database.Toolbox.FoxPro
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class FieldAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public Type Transformer { get; }

        public FieldAttribute(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public FieldAttribute(string name, Type transformer)
        {
            Name = name;
            Transformer = transformer;
        }

        public FieldAttribute(Type transformer)
        {
            Transformer = transformer;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fine with the performance of the `ReadHeader` method, as it's only called once. I'm mostly concerned with the performance of `ReadRecord`.

Comment: _I've tried doing some profiling on it_ - what have you tried? Did you use the VS profiler or some other one?

Comment: Could you describe in a little bit more detail what each of the methods is doing? The code is really hard to read.

Comment: For profiling I used the CPU usage profiler in Visual Studio Community 2017. Sure, let me edit the question to add some additional detail. Is there anything specific that you need to know?

Comment: Some general ideas about the algorithm would be great like, here I open the file, read this and that by skipping/reading bytes/strings, converting something, I use a stream, I don't use a stream, I load the entire file into memory, or I'm looking for numbers etc. Don't comment every line ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t I added some clarifying information. Let me know if there's anything else you'd like me to add!

Comment: You're using `dynamic` with the `transformer.Transform(value)`. Are you doing a lot there? This might be one of the bottlenecks. Do you really need to use `dynamic` here? Could you add this method to your question?

Comment: @t3chb0t That's the FoxProTransformer. Right now it just transforms the letter X to a boolean, because the database uses varchars with X or blank instead of boolean columns. I suppose I could switch it off of `dynamic`. Is there a performance penalty for using `dynamic` instead of `object`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> TranslateBuffer(dataBuffer.Skip(fieldStart).Take(fieldLength).ToArray(), field);
> ```

You are creating a `char[]` here but later you pass it as a read-only-collection:

> ```
> TranslateBuffer(IReadOnlyCollection<byte> buffer, FoxProField field)
> ```

only to loop over it again and turn it into a string:

> ```
> string.Join("", buffer.Select(x => (char)x)).TrimEnd()
> ```

I suggest converting it to `char` in the first pass:

```
TranslateBuffer(
    dataBuffer
        .Skip(fieldStart)
        .Take(fieldLength)
        .Select(x => (char)x)
        .ToArray()
```

and later use one of the string overloads that accepts an array:

```
int.TryParse(new string(buffer).TrimEnd(), out var val) ? val : 0;
```

This way you could save a few loops over the buffer.

Even better you could turn the buffer into a `string` at the top and use it later to clean-up the code a little bit:

```
var value = new string(buffer).TrimEnd();
...
int.TryParse(value, out var number) ? number : 0;
```

---

> ```
> var validYear = int.TryParse(string.Join("", buffer.Take(4).Select(x => (char)x)), out var year);
> var validMonth = int.TryParse(string.Join("", buffer.Skip(4).Take(2).Select(x => (char)x)), out var month);
> var validDay = int.TryParse(string.Join("", buffer.Skip(6).Take(2).Select(x => (char)x)), out var day);
> if (validDay && validMonth && validYear) return new DateTime(year, month, day);
> ```

For this entire part I'd use a single string that I guess has the form `Yeay-Month-Day` or something similar and use the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method or the alternative one [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) with the appropriate format. With this you could save another a few LINQ cycles for the `Skip` and `Take`.

---

Another bottleneck might be the `dataBuffer` and the `Skip` that you use a lot on it. If the buffer is long you should consider implementing `SkipFast` that can use an array and jump right away to the location where you want to skip it. The default `Skip` runs over the entire collection each time. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410858/performance-of-skip-and-take-in-linq-to-objects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002975/performance-of-skip-and-similar-functions-like-take) or many other questions about its performance and faster implementations.

Comment: I had no idea `string` had a constructor that takes a char array! That's super helpful. I think that and `DateTime.TryParseExact` are going to save me quite a bit of time. I was also unaware that `Skip` had such a performance problem.

Comment: This saved me about 10% CPU time, thanks!